# Match everything that isn't a comma followed by a space

Tags: php, regex

There are many similar questions, but none I found addresses exactly my case and I've been trying and trying with no luck.

I have a comma separated lists of values like so:

```
Apple, Banana, Carrot and Durian, Eggs
```

So some values are simple words, and others have multiple words. I need to wrap each value with a pair of quotes, and I found an answer that got me pretty close:

```
preg_replace( $list, '/([^,]+)/g', '"$1"' )
```

This generates:

```
"Apple","Banana","Carrot and Durian","Eggs"
```

But there is a problem: it removes the spaces after the commas. If I add the whitespace character `/([^,\s]+)/g` it doesn't remove the spaces after the commas anymore, but it matches the spaces inside the values:

```
"Apple", "Banana", "Carrot" "and" "Durian", "Eggs"
```

Live version at https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/31

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is the spaces after commas being removed a problem?

Comment: What if your text contains double quotes?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/32?

Comment: @Geek Josh the result is being displayed to the users, and the missing spaces cause the lists to be broken at the terms, rather than at the commas. It's just ugly and even confusing.

Comment: @Avinash Raj thanks, but it still deletes the spaces after the commas

Comment: I think you want that to happen.

Comment: Here it is https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/33

Comment: Replace `(\s*)([^,\s]+?)(\s*)(?=,|$)` with `$1"$2"$3`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Post it as answer.

Comment: This is not a PHP problem. You just want a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\K` to discard previously matched characters.

```
\s*\K([^,]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/33)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
$str ='Apple, Banana, Carrot and Durian, Eggs';

$result = '"' . strtr($str, [', '=>'", "']) . '"';
```